# How to get Price from Google Console Subscription and show in android text view

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, subscription

I am using android `com.android.billingclient:billing:3.0.3` in my project, I have created subscription plan in google play console.

How to get subscription price from google play console and show it into andriod TextView???

In my `MainActivity.java` I am using code like below, help me how to solve this OR send me all new code according to you.

```
private final BillingClient billingClient = null;

public void getPrices() {
    final List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();

    skuList.add("yearly_subscription");
    SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
    params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);

    assert false;
    billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(),
            (billingResult, skuDetailsList) -> {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && skuDetailsList != null) {
                    for (SkuDetails skuDetails : skuDetailsList) {

                        String price = skuDetails.getPrice();

                        mSkuDetailsMap.put(skuDetails.getSku(), skuDetails);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), price + "  price", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            });
}
```

Comment: You've got the String representation of the price in your variable `price` so it should just be `mTextView.setText(price)`.. am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, but above SKUcode is not fetching price from Google console...

Comment: And you've checked that "yearly_subscription" exactly matches the product ID in the Play Console? No typos?

Comment: Yes, its "yearly_subscription"... am i missing something in SKU

Comment: Not that I can see. What's the `assert false` for and why is your `billingClient` null? Have you initialized it in `onResume()`?